# How to remove a Nuget package form solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

When I go on the "Manage Nuget packages for solution" in VS2015, I've a list of packages. Some of them are not used anymore, by any project(I don't see any checkbox on the right).

If I remove the corresponding nuget folder from the solution, it indicates me that I've some missing Nuget package on the next start.

On the right, the button to uninstall is grayed out.

How do I do to remove those package from the solution?

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot showing my nuget pane:
[image]

Comment: The uninstall from "Manage Nuget Packages" is the right way to do it, have you tried closing and reopening the solution? Be sure to uninstall the packages from the main project of the solution and not from a "child" project. Open the project you want them removed and open package manager from there. Also you might want to check "Tools - Extensions and updates" if there is an update for Nuget Package manager available.

Comment: @Esko I'm doing it directly on the solution(and I don't know what you mean by child project). I've even closed and restarted Visual studio(and the computer). I only have updates for azure, git and sql server.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question from the "Manage Nuget Packages" -window where the uninstall-button is greyed out?

Comment: @Esko I just updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: Hmm in solution explorer where do you right click? The solution or the project? Right click the ***project*** and then select "Manage Nuget Packages".

Answer (score 3):

One or more projects in your solution has that Nuget package installed. Right click on the project (not solution) and click "Manage Nuget Packages" from there you can uninstall the package. Note I click on the project and not solution:

[image]

Comment: I've 340 projects in my solution, I just cannot do this on every project. Some of my projects did use this in the past but not anymore. If one project is using this, there is a checkbox with a "partially selected" state in my screenshot

Comment: In fact it seems it is a requisite for another package

Comment: 340 projects? Woah that's some big solution :) If you don't know which project is using it you might find it by using Windows search for the folder "CommonServiceLocator". The project should have this folder under packages-folder.

Comment: Yes, 2.5million line of code, 15 developers on it since 8 years, a lot of things have been separated into separate project to ensure SoC. 

In fact what happened(I think) is that we did remove the reference in the project, and we were thinking it would remove the "need" for this package. Which is apparently not the case, I will have to look if there is a way to remove unused package from projects

Answer (score 1):

First, open your Package Manager Console. Then select your project from the dropdown list. And run the following commands for uninstalling nuget packages.

```
Get-Package
```

for getting all the package you have installed.

and then

```
Uninstall-Package YourPackageName
```

Comment: this doesn't remove pkg from **solution**